# QMainWindow disappears when you resize it vertically

Tags: c++, qt5, qmainwindow

if I try to resize my QMainWindow vertically, it quickly goes down the screen until it's no longer visible, but the size will never change, no matter if I enlarge or reduce it. 
I basically just show it and place several Buttons/VLayouts etc. in it, but never specify any kind of size policy.

main.cpp:

```
int __cdecl main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QApplication::setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(true);
    ...
    mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow->showMaximized();
    ...
    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

mainWindow.hpp:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
...
}
```

I thought that maybe a QWidget inside the window with a fixed size policy prevents the MainWindow from resizing, but it displays perfectly on my second screen which has a different resolution.

Using:

- QT5.14.2 (Components: Core, Widgets, Test, PrintSupport)
- build with mingw73_64
- C++17
- CMake 3.16.2

Additional Libraries:

- Boost 1.72
- GigaBASE (Database)

Hope someone can help, thank you in advance.

Comment: So on your second screen you can resize the window, but on the first not ? Did I undestand correctly?

Comment: No, what I wanted to say is that on the second screen, in windowed fullscreen mode, the window has a different size than on the first one, so I don't understand why I can't resize it.